# Android: OnBootReceiver: Exported receiver does not require permission

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, bootcompleted

I've created a `BroadcastReceiver`, which receives `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I've added it like so:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

However, I get the warning: **Exported receiver does not require permission.**
I've read about it on SO, but I don't fully understand it.

So could someone explain to this beginner :) why I'm getting this warning, and what to do against it (and why)?

Comment: it just means that anyone can call it, as it is public and does not require permission (a receiver can request a specific permission to be called)

Comment: @njzk2 but not adding it makes it stop working? I remember i tried one time and it didn't work but my code had some issues so I'm not sure.

Comment: @njzk2 So actually, I don't have to do anything against it?

Comment: @Merlin : you can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: Does this warning get displayed still -after cleaning and rescanning Lint warnings ? I have something similar in my manifest _but no warnings_ - and trying to decide if I should add `exported="false"` or not. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112470/android-exported-receiver-does-not-require-permission-on-receivers-meant-to)

Answer (score 8):

The warning

> Exported receiver does not require permission

means,
You have an intent-filter with some action (which means by default you have `android:exported="true"` set and it can now receive broadcasts from **ANY** broadcasters outside of your application)
Since it can receive broadcasts from **ANY** broadcasters outside of your application, it warns you by saying "Hey, are you sure **ANY** broadcaster can invoke you? In my opinion, it is better if you allow only those broadcasters to invoke you that has the permission you have set for this receiver through **android:permission**"

Hope this is clear!!!

Comment: what if it's just part of the API ? like in this example the boot complete? or like when a new camera image was taken (using this: http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE ) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove this warning by adding `android:exported="false"` to the receiver tag (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526028/757073)

Comment: And if you set exported to false, can it still be called when boot completed?