# Broadcast receiver is not called

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

In my Fragment, I have a button, when button pressed, I broadcast a custom intent in following way:

```
package com.my.store.fragments.shopping;

public class ShoppingFragment extends Fragment{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
       super.onStart()

       myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                broadcastMyIntent(v);
             }
       });
    }

    public void broadcastMyIntent(View view){
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction("com.my.store.fragments.shopping.CUSTOM_INTENT");
     getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Then, I defined a broadcast receiver:

```
package com.my.store.utils;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receive my intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I register the receiver in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application
    ...>
    <activity ...>
       ...
    </activity>

    <!--this is the receiver which doesn't work-->
    <receiver android:name="com.my.store.utils.MyReceiver"> 
          <action android:name="com.my.store.fragments.shopping.CUSTOM_INTENT"/>
    </receiver>

    <!--I have another receiver here, it is working fine-->
   <receiver android:name="com.my.store.utils.AnotherReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I run my app, when I press the button, my receiver isn't called. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to surround your `<action>` element with an `<intent-filter>` container.

Comment: I didn't forget that, I just didn't include <intent-filter> because this link suggests me not to do that (because I got the same warning as the link mentioned): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112470/android-exported-receiver-does-not-require-permission-on-receivers-meant-to

Comment: In the example you showed the answer is stating only to do that if you're using an `Intent` with the class name rather than an action string. You can do that by using Intent it = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class) - So either you use this syntax or you surround your action element with an intent-filter container.

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!--this is the receiver which doesn't work-->
<receiver android:name="com.my.store.utils.MyReceiver"> 
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.my.store.fragments.shopping.CUSTOM_INTENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I got "Exported receiver does not require 
 permission" in my AndroidManifest.xml when I include the <intent-filter> that's why I removed that

Comment: @Mellon Maybe you need add ```<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />``` under ```<intent-filter>```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<receiver android:name="com.my.store.utils.MyReceiver"> 
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.my.store.fragments.shopping.CUSTOM_INTENT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```