# How can I link from an e-mail to a Xamarin Android app without additional dependencies?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to link to my app from an e-mail. The Xamarin documentations describes how to link to an app:

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-android/

However, it does that by referring to an additional component (Rivets) and it focuses on linking by code:

```
Rivets.AppLinks.Navigator.Navigate("http://location/of/your/html/file.html");
```

and it requires to publish a page:

> Publish this page somewhere on the internet, or at a location your Android app can reach.

This feels like a complex solution for a very simple problem. I want to link from an e-mail to my app in a way that just works, even if my website would not work and preferably without additional components. I tried to do that based on explanations that focus on Android Java applications. 
This
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526028
and this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870

I did not succeed for my Xamarin app. Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="AndroidLink.AndroidLink" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="AndroidLink" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="twitter.com" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I send myself an e-mail with the following content `http://twitter.com/status/1234` and click on that link in the Gmail app, the browser is opened, instead of my App.

Hopefully, this problem is solvable with Xamarin Android. Please note that:

1. I want to link from an e-mail to my app.
2. I prefer a working solution, even if my website would be down.
3. I prefer the browser not to be opened.

In case, it is relevant, here is my C# code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        var data = Intent.Data;
        if (data != null)
        {
            var scheme = data.Scheme;
            var host = data.Host;
            var pathSegments = data.PathSegments;
            button.Text = pathSegments.Count.ToString();
        }

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add an Intent filter for URI scheme, Android will let you choose a default app. Are you sure you haven't selected an app for twitter.com? Try using a scheme or domain that is unique.

Comment: You also might want to consider using an IntentFilter attribute in your code instead of the manifest file.  See http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.IntentFilterAttribute%2f*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sure I have not selected an app for twitter.com. The problem is also for other websites.

Comment: Same problem when adding IntentFilter in code, also for another website: [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, DataHost = "geenstijl.nl", DataScheme = "http")]

Comment: Just tried: same problem for other schemes.

Comment: I have just tried the following `IntentFilter` in my app and it works just fine: `[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
        DataScheme = "http", DataHost = "blog.ostebaronen.dk")]`. `Intent.Data` in `OnCreate` is poplulated with the entire URL. I just sent an SMS to myself with a URL which matches the DataHost.

Comment: @Daan did you find the solution for opening app through link from browser.